# Understanding how kernel symbols related to my app in perf

Tags: linux, performance, networking, perf

I'm trying to profile bottlenecks in my program.
I'm using `perf` as `sudo perf record -agi -F 10000 -p $(pidof myapp)`
This is part of the output I see with `sudo perf report -g graph,0.01`

```
+   63.68%     0.00%  my_thread    [kernel.kallsyms]    [k] entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe
+   63.60%     0.49%  my_thread    [kernel.kallsyms]    [k] do_syscall_64
+   49.35%     0.14%  my_thread    libpthread-2.27.so   [.] __libc_write
+   49.08%     0.04%  my_thread    [kernel.kallsyms]    [k] __x64_sys_write
+   49.04%     0.02%  my_thread    [kernel.kallsyms]    [k] ksys_write
+   48.92%     0.07%  my_thread    [kernel.kallsyms]    [k] vfs_write
+   48.78%     0.03%  my_thread    [kernel.kallsyms]    [k] __vfs_write
+   48.67%     0.12%  my_thread    [kernel.kallsyms]    [k] sock_write_iter
+   48.65%     0.07%  my_thread    [kernel.kallsyms]    [k] new_sync_write
+   48.53%     0.01%  my_thread    [kernel.kallsyms]    [k] sock_sendmsg
+   48.44%     0.07%  my_thread    [kernel.kallsyms]    [k] inet_sendmsg
```

Which seems like network stack in the kernel. It's very reasonable according to what my app does.
Later below I see my userspace functions do processing on the received data.

But nowhere  I see the connection - I mean by that:  I don't see my userspace functions call some `read()`/`write()`.

- Is there a way to see how much time is spent on `read()`/`write()` (in case the socket is blocking) ?
- Is there a way to see stack trace from kernel network stack with my application? So I'll know which function exactly is doing the heavy networking load ? e.g. see who `write()` all the time?
  More specifically; Let's say I have 3 functions, which one is the one cause all this perf output?

```
void func1() {
  // ...
  read();
  // ...
}
void func2() {
  // ...
  write();
  // ...
}
void func3() {
  // ...
  write();
  // ...
}
```

--- Update ---
I am using `-g`, but still cannot see the connection to my code:

```
-   43.68%     0.86%  my_thread       [kernel.kallsyms]    [k] do_syscall_64
   - 42.81% do_syscall_64
      - 25.34% __x64_sys_write
         - 25.31% ksys_write
            - 25.18% vfs_write
               - 24.99% __vfs_write
                  - 24.79% new_sync_write
                     - sock_write_iter
                        - 24.60% sock_sendmsg
                           - 24.42% inet_sendmsg
                              - 24.32% tcp_sendmsg
                                 - 23.85% tcp_sendmsg_locked
                                    - 22.09% tcp_push
                                       - 21.98% __tcp_push_pending_frames
                                          - 21.87% tcp_write_xmit
                                             - 21.25% __tcp_transmit_skb
                                                - 20.70% ip_queue_xmit
                                                   - 20.61% __ip_queue_xmit
                                                      - 20.45% ip_local_out
                                                         - 20.27% ip_output
                                                            - 20.16% ip_finish_output
                                                               - 20.01% ip_finish_output2
                                                                  - 18.50% __local_bh_enable_ip
                                                                     - do_softirq.part.21
                                                                        - do_softirq_own_stack
                                                                           - 18.37% __softirqentry_text_start
                                                                              - 18.07% net_rx_action
                                                                                 - 17.92% process_backlog
                                                                                    - 17.78% __netif_receive_skb
                                                                                       - 17.74% __netif_receive_skb_one_core
                                                                                          - 17.53% ip_rcv
                                                                                             - 17.44% ip_rcv_finish
                                                                                                - 17.40% ip_local_deliver
                                                                                                   - 17.37% ip_local_deliver_finish
                                                                                                      - 17.27% ip_protocol_deliver_rcu
                                                                                                         - 17.10% tcp_v4_rcv
                                                                                                            - 16.42% tcp_v4_do_rcv
                                                                                                               - 16.27% tcp_rcv_established
                                                                                                                  - 14.49% tcp_data_queue
                                                                                                                     - 14.28% sock_def_readable
                                                                                                                        - __wake_up_sync_key
                                                                                                                          __wake_up_common_lock
                                                                                                                          _raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore
```

Comment: `perf record` has a `-g` option to record stack snapshots.  You can use that for top-down perf analysis and figure out which functions are making expensive calls.

Comment: @PeterCordes I am using `-g`, but still cannot see the connection to my code. Please see updated question for example.

Comment: Looks like it's easier to view with `valgrind` and `kcachegrind` ([link](https://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2011/09/profile-c-application-with-callgrind-kcachegrind.html)). I currently don't know how it can be done with `perf`.

Comment: @hudac, you can also check `strace ./myapp` output (and grep it for write), or try it with '-k' option `strace -k ./myapp` ([man strace](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) "`-k` *Print the execution stack trace of the traced processes  after each system call.*"). There should be some glibc function which calls write internally. You have some write on socket. It can be some internal glibc for hostname or other kind of name resolving (nss).

Comment: Thanks @osgx. Though I don't get the bottle neck function like that.
I need to write a script and start filtering how many times `write()` was called from each stack.